# How can one send multiple word OR queries to Google?

Tags: google-search

I am trying to send Google a search query with several units, some containing more than one word, separated by the boolean operator OR. Usually I'd write:
`(Oneword, Two words, Something containing four words, anotheroneword, word)`.
However, Google doesn't seem to understand that.

`OR` or `|` do work, however the operation is obviously only performed on the words to each side of the operator, making it useless for multiple word queries.

I also tried 
`"First Query" OR "Second Query"` yet that seems to bring the exact same results as simply searching for `First Query`.

Comment: Google does not support this.

Comment: Your last statement with "First Query" OR "Second Query" seemingly returning the same results as "First Query", this could be just that "First Query" is a better match, with "Second Query" coming lower down the results. If I search for "cat definition" OR "dog definition", (something possibly equally likely), results from both phrases are returned on the first page of results.

Comment: @GivenSurname, `"First Query" OR "Second Query"` is the correct query.  Do you see any difference in the "about x number of results"?

Answer (score 6):

Extracted from [Google's search tips](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/static.py?page=guide.cs&guide=1221265&answer=136861&rd=3), you can enclose your individual search queries with double quotes and separate them with a `OR` or `|` operator.

```
"Apple Pie" OR "Stack Exchange" OR Programming
```

Comment: The square brackets are not required in the search terms; the Google help will just `use square brackets [ ] to denote queries`. Also, according to Google, `OR` must be all caps. Otherwise, this is the right answer.

Comment: Oops, you're right. Misread on my part.

Comment: Quoting terms makes them phrases. The OP wants:  (A AND B) OR (C AND D), not "A B" OR "C D"

Comment: @Jin, Dude, the square brackets are just wrong. They [don't mean what you think they mean](https://www.quora.com/How-did-the-convention-originate-at-Google-of-referring-to-search-queries-in-square-brackets). I'll edit them out.